# Show that $a_n=(n+1)^{\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}} \to e$ when $n \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that $a_n=(n+1)^{\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}} \to e$ when $n \to \infty$ Can you give me a hint? I can't use L'Hopital. Thanks.

Comment: $(n+1) = e^{\log(n+1)} \implies (n+1)^{1/\log(n+1)} = e^{\log(n+1)/\log(n+1)} = ...$

Answer (score 1):

$${{(n+1)}^{\frac{1}{\ln (n+1)}}}={{(n+1)}^{\frac{\ln e}{\ln (n+1)}}}={{(n+1)}^{\log _{n+1}^{e}}}={{e}^{\log _{n+1}^{n+1}}}=e$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint 1: It's a trick question. The solution is really, really, really easy.

Hint 2: Take a spreadsheet program and calculate the values for n = 1 to 10.